# Some commit changes disappeared after merging

Tags: git

I was working in branch `otherIssue`. I do some work in file `foo.bar` and some other files. I commit it to `d379865`.

Then checkout to branch `issue`, merge `otherIssue` to `issue` and push to upstreap.

After that *dev1* do some work on his local `issue` in other files without changing `foo.bar`. (commit `4fb65b2`). And merge upstream's `issue` to his `issue`. After that my changes *disappeared*.

I don't see any changes in `foo.bar` using `git show c1c25b5` and `git show 4fb65b2`.

My graph:

```
* |   c1c25b5 - (9 hours ago) NO CHANGES Merge branch 'issue' of repo:project into issue - dev1
|\ \  
| * | 4c95813 - (14 hours ago) MY CHANGES IS STILL HERE - dev2
| * |   a08ccdb - (14 hours ago) Merge branch 'otherIssue' into issue - dev2
| |\ \  
| | |/  
| | * d379865 - (14 hours ago) otherIssue: MY CHANGES IS HERE - dev2
| | * 521d54d - (19 hours ago) otherIssue: some changes - dev2
* | | 4fb65b2 - (11 hours ago) issue: somechanges - dev1
|/ /  
* | b3baeed - (19 hours ago) issue: - dev1
```

I can restore changes without problems, but I can't understand **how could this happen?**

---

```
$ MERGE_COMMIT=c1c25b5
$ BRANCH_ONE=c1c25b5^1
$ BRANCH_TWO=c1c25b5^2
$ COMMON_ANCESTOR=b3baeed
$ FILE_WITH_MISSING="path/to/foo.bar"

$ git show $MERGE_COMMIT | grep $FILE_WITH_MISSING | wc -l
  0 # Why??
$ git diff $MERGE_COMMIT..$COMMON_ANCESTOR -- $FILE_WITH_MISSING | wc -l
  0
$ git diff $BRANCH_ONE..$COMMON_ANCESTOR -- $FILE_WITH_MISSING | wc -l
  0
$ git diff $BRANCH_TWO..$COMMON_ANCESTOR -- $FILE_WITH_MISSING | wc -l
  210
$ 
$ git log -p $COMMON_ANCESTOR..$BRANCH_ONE | grep "$FILE_WITH_MISSING" | wc -l
  0
$ git log -p $COMMON_ANCESTOR..$BRANCH_TWO | grep "$FILE_WITH_MISSING" | wc -l
  3
$
```

---

There are question "[Git; code disappeared after merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527276/git-code-disappeared-after-merge)", but there are no explanation of this incident.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "checkout to branch issue, merge otherIssue to origin/issue."? `issue` isn't the same branch as `origin/issue`! merging `issue` and `otherIssue` doesn't automatically merge the upstream branch.

Comment: @joker yes, I understand. It was pushed to upstream after merge. I suppose that there was push after each commit.