# How to restore git history

Tags: git, github, git-branch

One of our developers copied a file from one branch to another and rewrote the file's history. What is the best way to restore it.

```
   original__________________________________________________(commits d)____(commits e)___(no commit history for a, b, c in master)
    |                                            |
    |                                         (copied)
    |                                            |
    |                                            |
    |__(commits a)__(commits b)___(commits c)_____
```

Comment: Copied or moved?

Comment: copied file content from another branch and committed it in master, move would have kept the history intact I believe

Comment: What do you mean by "rewrote the files history"?

Comment: changes and commit messages of a, b, c won't be visible on original branch. From original branch(master) will see that everything done in (a,b,c,d) in one commit 'd'.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but see https://stackoverflow.com/q/48294526/1256452

Answer (score 2):

Make a new branch from the original. This is your backup with every commit after the file was copied.

```
git checkout -b backup
```

Now reset original to the last commit before the file was copied over.

```
git checkout original && git reset SHA --hard
```

Merge the branch with commits a-c into original.

```
git merge branchname
```

Check out your backup and rebase it

```
git checkout backup && git rebase original
```

You will have a merge conflict telling you 'both added x`, resolve this conflict and continue the rebase.

Now go back to original and merge the backup back

```
git checkout original && git merge backup
```

This should do it.