# Renaming file name to older name loses history in Git

Tags: git

I have two files in my git repo.

- Editor.cs
- Editor2.cs

The first file is the older version of this class, which I kept around until I was sure the new version (Editor2.cs) worked.

Now, I want to delete *Editor.cs* and rename *Editor2.cs* to *Editor.cs*.  However, when I do this in git (i.e., do a **git rm** on Editor.cs, then a **git mv** on Editor2.cs to Editor.cs), I seem to lose the history of Editor2.cs.

That is, when I view the log for the (newly renamed) Editor.cs, it shows me the history for the *original* Editor.cs (not Editor2.cs).

I've tried using **git log --follow** and it still shows me the history for the wrong file.

Sorry if this is confusing...

Thanks

Comment: Related, but not exactly a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48294526/1256452

Answer (score 2):

There are some things you can do, if you want `git log --follow` to follow your file.  It has nothing to do with using `git mv`, though.  I will describe how Git works, and you can then decide what, if anything, you wish to do.

In fact, Git does not lose the history of the file, when you do what you are suggesting.  Git *does* lose the ability to *follow* that history via `git log --follow`.  This seemingly contradictory state is because Git **never had the history of *any* file in the first place.**

What Git has—what's stored in the repository—is a series of *commits*.  Each commit is a complete snapshot of *all* files (as of that commit).  When you  run `git log` (without `--follow`), Git shows you these commits, one at a time, in some order.  If the order is based on when the commits were made,<sup>1</sup> that shows you the history—or at least some subset of the history.  But that's the history of *commits*, not of files.

Using `git log --follow` tells Git: *Keep some commits hidden. Walk through the commit history as usual, but only **tell** me about commits where the difference between the immediate predecessor of this commit, and this commit itself, **changed** the one file I name on the command line.*  **This is not file history; this is a subset of commit history, based on one file's name.**

The trick is that with `--follow`, Git will automatically *switch* from looking for a file named, say, `new.txt`, to a file named, say, `old.txt`, *if and when* the change in some commit was to *rename* the file.  This particular trick is enabled in a somewhat peculiar fashion, though.  Git uses *rename detection*, in which it compares two commits and tries to *guess* (rather than remembering) whether some file(s) were renamed across those commits.<sup>2</sup>

To compare the parent commit to the child commit (two commits made in succession), Git extracts—well, virtually extracts—each of the two commits.  It then looks at all the file *names* in each of the two commits.  A file named `read.me` in the old commit is automatically *assumed* to be "the same" file as `read.me` in the new commit.  But if the old commit has an `old.txt` and the new one does not, while the new commit has a `new.txt` and the old one does not have this file, *then*—for rename detection at least—Git will look at the *contents* of the two files.  If what's in `old.txt` is sufficiently similar to what's in `new.txt`,<sup>3</sup> Git decrees that these must be "the same" file, and therefore, `old.txt` got renamed to `new.txt`.

Git doesn't look at the file's *names* here, but instead, at the data.<sup>4</sup>  So it won't detect `Editor.cs` as similar to `Editor2.cs` unless the contents really are pretty similar.  But more importantly, it will only *compare* the two files' content if there is one commit (the parent) that has only *one* of the files by one of those names, followed immediately by a second commit (the child) that has just one of those files (by the other name).  If one commit has both files, and the other commit has one file, Git will just say the file was added (parent lacks + child has) or deleted (parent has + child lacks).

Thus, to get this detected as "same file but different name", you will need to make one commit that has only *one* of those files, followed by a newer commit that has only *the other* of those files.  The content of the two files must also be sufficiently similar.  "Exactly the same" is best—a 100% identical match is found much faster than a lesser match—and here using `git mv` can guarantee that you make a commit that has a 100% matching file under a changed name, which `git log --follow` is guaranteed to detect.  But **the key is to have the old name vanish and the new name appear, all in one commit.**  In your case, that means you will need to *remove* the new file, commit, then either:

- *rename the old file in place and commit again* (making a 100% match), followed by *replace the old file content with the new content* (no name change = Git believes file is the same), or
- *remove the old file and create the new one and commit*, so that there is a detectable rename, which will actually be detected if and only if the contents are 50% or more similar.

Doing either of these should result in `git log --follow` detecting a rename from the new name to the old name, after which `git log --follow` will start looking for the *old* name, and suppressing commits that do not modify a file that has the *old* name.

---

<sup>1</sup>By default, the order is *almost, but not quite,* the order commits were made in.  It's actually rather complicated.  Adding `--topo-order` enforces a strict topologically-correct order, although given branching and merging, some commits will have no ancestor/descendant relationships.

<sup>2</sup>One advantage of doing rename detection like this is that Git can detect renames when comparing commits that are not immediately adjacent, such as when doing merges.  The disadvantage is obvious: it's hard!  It would be much easier to record "file X was renamed".  Other version control systems do that.

<sup>3</sup>The default is to require that the files be "50% similar", using a computed similarity index.  When using `git diff` you can tune this.  When using `git log --follow` you get just the 50% number.

<sup>4</sup>The similarity index is given a 1% boost if the file's path names have the same final component.  That is, `dir/sub/file.txt` might be 49% similar to `dir2/sub2/xyz.txt` and 49% similar to `dir2/sub2/file.txt`, but the latter has the same `file.txt` final component, so it gets boosted to the magic 50% mark.

Comment: I appreciate this thoughtful and comprehensive answer. I tried to follow your suggested steps, but the result seems to be the same--I still see the history for the old class. At any rate, I went ahead and pushed the new (renamed) version. I told my teammates that, if they need the actual history, they can just dig through the commits. Thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing, but I suspect you are using Java, which makes this harder as the name of the class and the name of the file must match (which means you can't have a 100% match for a single file across some renames). If you could, you could make one commit that renames `class` to `old-class`, leaving `new-class` in place, then a second commit that renames `new-class` to `class`, leaving everything else in place, and only then make any changes to adapt things. Git would look at the commits one step at a time as it moves backwards and see both renames (though you get only one `--follow` argument).