# Will removing a file from Git history also remove its replacement?

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I have found out how to remove a file from git's history, but when I tried to remove a file (root `Makefile`) that had been replaced by another (`Makefile` in subdirectory moved to root), the [method I used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2164581/remove-file-from-git-repository-history) removed the replacement as well.

Here is the exact command I used:

`git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch Makefile'`

Is there any way to do this without removing the replacement? If so, how?

Note: I am asking about a way to retain the history of the replacement file. I do have the option of removing both and restoring the current one from backup, which would lose history. If there is no other option, I will do that because I want the original file gone.

Comment: Why the other file was removed is heavily dependent on the exact method you use (specific commands, options, etc.).  Looking at the article you linked, it seems you used `filter-branch`; in that case, you just need filters defined so as to remove the original file while leaving the later file untouched.  I assume that's what you meant to write, but without the specific commands used we can't say why it might have turned out different.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger, good point. Question has been edited to have the original command.

Comment: Hmm... I think I previously misread a key phrase, though the command did help clarify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note: I am asking about a way to retain the history of the replacement file.

You need to arrange to remove only the original file.  How to do that is a bit tricky.

The key to understanding the problem here is simple: *Git does not have file history.*  There is no such thing!  (See also [Missing deletion of lines in file history (git)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48294526/1256452))

The history that Git does have is *commit history*.  More precisely, the commits *are* the history: each commit has a backwards link, to its parent commit.  (For merge commits, the backwards link goes to at least two parents.)  Each commit contains a full snapshot of all files, so by having Git walk through *commit* history, and asking questions about what files are *in each commit*, you can have Git synthesize a pretend file history.  But it's not actually *there*, it's *computed from what **is** there*.

All commits in a Git repository are completely read-only.  This includes their backwards links: the link holds the "true name" (hash ID) of the parent commit(s), and the true name of a commit depends on its content.  That makes it impossible to change history.  Git's `filter-branch` does not even try to do that.  What it does instead is simple: it *copies* every commit (well, every commit you tell it to copy), while applying whatever filter(s) you specified.  For each existing commit, Git:

- extracts the commit into a temporary work area;
- applies your filters; and
- commits the result, as a new commit.

If the new commit is 100%, bit-for-bit identical to the original commit, you get back the original commit with its original hash ID.  However, as soon as there is any change at all, you get back a different commit, with a different hash ID.  The main cleverness inside filter-branch is that it defines a *mapping* from original hash ID (original commit) to new hash ID (copied commit), and as it copies, it always replaces the *parent* hash IDs with their mapped versions.

What this means is that you can take a nice, simple graph like:

```
A  <-B  <-C   <--master
```

(where each uppercase letter stands in for the actual commit hash ID, and the arrows are the stored hash IDs in each commit or in the name `master`) and filter it.  If you change anything about commit `A`, you get a new, different commit `A'`, and the copy of `B` will point back to `A'` rather than to `A`.  The copy of `C'` will point back to `B'`.  This is true even if you also change something while copying `B` and `C`.  The result is:

```
A  <-B  <-C   <--master
A' <-B' <-C'
```

The last thing filter-branch does is rip the *names* off the original chains of commits and make them point to the new chains:

```
A  <-B  <-C      [refs/original/refs/heads/master]
A' <-B' <-C'  <-- master
```

Running `git log`, or anything thing displays the commits—the history—now starts at `C'` and works backwards.  The history shown, or synthesized, is from the new, copied commits.

In your original series of commits, you have some commits that contain a file named `Makefile` that you *don't* want them to contain.  Then you have a series of other commits that contain a file named `Makefile` that you *do* want them to contain.  Your job, in your filter, is to distinguish between these two sets of commits.  Instead of:

> ```
> git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch Makefile'
> ```

you want, e.g.:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter magic-script
```

(plus any other options you like<sup>1</sup>).  The hard part is deciding what goes into this `magic-script`, because what you want is: "if commit being copied has wrong makefile, remove it, if not, don't".  But how will you test that?

There are multiple answers, including using `--tree-filter` instead of `--index-filter`: a tree filter, which is much (**much**) slower, literally extracts each commit, so that you can inspect the files in it, and builds the new commit from the extracted files.

The index filter leaves the extracted commit in the index (this is a special filter-branch temporary index but you generally don't need to care about that).  This is why you were using `git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch Makefile`: that removes the file named `Makefile` from the index, after which filter-branch builds the new commit from the index.  Index operations, which take place in a special Git-only file, are much faster than general file system operations.  But they don't let you *inspect* the file named `Makefile`, in order to make a decision about it.

There is another way to deal with this, though.  Suppose, in our idealized three-commit repository `A-B-C` above, you fixed the Makefile at commit `C`, then added several more commits `D-E-F-G` or whatever.  What you want to do in *this* case is use a test of the form:

- If the current, being-filtered commit is `B` or any of its ancestors such as `A`, remove the file named `Makefile`.
- Otherwise (current commit is `C` or later), leave the file named `Makefile`.

This, as it turns out, *is* possible to do.  The *plumbing command* `git merge-base --is-ancestor` performs this kind of ancestry test, and is usable in a shell script `if` test:

```
if git merge-base --is-ancestor $GIT_COMMIT <hash>; then
    git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch Makefile;
fi
```

(the "is ancestor" test includes equality, so the `<hash>` here would be the literal hash ID of commit `B`).  Put this whole thing inside single quotes, with the appropriate hash ID in place, and you have the filter you probably want.

(Where it can go wrong is if there are multiple cases where `Makefile` should or should not be removed.  If you have enough time, and/or a RAM-based file system with enough space, you can use `--tree-filter` and examine the actual `Makefile`.  Or, you can get very fancy and use plumbing commands to examine the Git object whose hash ID is stored in the index, and use `--index-filter`, but that's a little bit tricky.)

---

<sup>1</sup>You might still want `-f` here, and also things like `--tag-name-filter cat` and `-- --all`.  Note that `-f` exists to tell filter-branch that if a previous filter-branch left behind a `refs/original/` name-space, it's OK to destroy that.  It's always wise to run these operations on a *copy* of the repository (a clone: perhaps one made with `git clone --mirror`) in case you goof things up, in which case the `refs/original/` stuff is unnecessary caution: you've already used all necessary caution!

Answer (score 1):

To do this, first you need to identify the last commit(s) that contain the old file (which you want removed), and the earliest commit(s) that contain the new file you want to retain.  You can then apply your filter to only the older commits.

For example if you have

```
o -- o -- o -- o -- A -- x -- x -- x <--(master)
```

where the old file is present in commits marked `o`, but commit `A` moved the newer file (which you want to keep) to the root: then you want to leave `A` and the `x` commits untouched.

To do that with `filter-branch` either you need a filter that "knows" what commit it's editing, or you need to apply the filter only to the `o` commits.  The latter is easier, but in that case you'd get a split history

```
o -- o -- o -- o -- A -- x -- x -- x <--(master)

o' -- o' -- o' -- o'
```

and you'd have to follow up by "re-parenting" `A` to the last `o'` commit.  That can also be done with `filter-branch` (using `--parent-filter`), but this still only deals with one line of history - or, at least, only one "transition" commit where you switched files.  If you have multiple commits that "introduce" the change between files (i.e. because the change propagated across branches via merges), then this procedure will quickly get more and more complicated.

A better solution would be to consider the BFG Repo Cleaner.  It's specialized to the purpose of removing unwanted history, so (1) it's faster, and (2) it's often easier.  It can be configured to "protect" some commits and only edit others.  Please see the project's page and docs for more details (https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/)