# Git workflow - extension fork - how to reconcile diverged fork?

Tags: git

This must be a well understood problem, yet I seem to be unable to find relevant information.

TL;DR: git's mapping between code of the two branches seems broken due to messy history of the branches.

### The setup:

I am maintaining an "extension" fork. I.e.:

- I have a `fork` repository, which is a copy of an `origin`. (And I have a local repository, which distinguishes `fork` and `origin` remotes.)
- Fork contains custom extension to the project. I commit my changes onto `fork/master`.
- Whenever there is an update of `origin/master`, I merge it into `fork/master`. (I.e., I directly fetch and merge `origin/master` into local repository and push into `fork/master`.)
- In time, the 'fork/master' sometimes diverges from master significantly, but later converges back again, so most of the code is still in a "1-1" relation.

### The problem:

This way, "diverged" commits accumulate on `fork/master` (hundreds of them). Lately, I have been experiencing (more and more) problems with conflict resolution:

- Git merge produces a lot of conflicts whose cause is unclear.
- Git merge often autoresolves conflicts incorrectly. In practice this means that after a merge, I often find "random" pieces of code inserted or deleted at "random" places. These changes are utterly wrong, but were applied without me having to review them.
- (The code mapping between code sections is totally broken, which obviously is the cause of the problem yet makes it impossible to manually review the automatically-applied changes in the merge commit.)

I assume that the cause is the three-way merge which tries to take into account entire commit history of the branches since first diverged commit.

### Solution attempt:

I tried to "rebase" the fork into a single squashed commit on top of `origin/master` and merge this branch into `fork/master`:

```
git checkout -b master_rebased master
git reset --soft origin/master
git commit
git checkout master
git merge master_rebased`
```

This way `fork/master` has now in fact two alternative histories. I argued that git would always automatically compute the "shortest" diverge path (fully containing entire changeset) before computing merges or diverge statistics, but no - git still claims that my branch is hundreds commit ahead of `origin/master`.

Of course, I can simply throw out old `fork/master` and replace it by the rebased master, but it sounds as a very unclear way of dealing with the problem, which probably means that I am missing something.

### Summary:

So the questions basically are:

1) What is the cleanest way to reconcile a diverged branch?

2) What is the proper git workflow to maintain a long term extension fork?

3) Alternatively: what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

> 3. Alternatively: what am I missing?

Well, I was obviously missing proper search keywords - "long-lived topic branch" or "long-lived feature branch".

> 2. What is the proper git workflow to maintain a long term extension fork?

Searching leads to a bunch of approaches, which however do not reveal anything new. The recommended ways are:

- To simply use merges. Obviously does not solve my problem, but is the easiest way unless conflict resolution problems pop up.
- To use rebases, while rewriting/discarding commit history time to time.

  This comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/7752610/6922501 shows how to deal with the problem of rewriting someone else's history - basicaly, to have the affected party rebase their work onto the rebased branch.
- To use git rerere, which basicaly records resolutions of merge conflicts and replays them automatically whenever the same conflict appears multiple times.

> 1. What is the cleanest way to reconcile a diverged branch?

I am still unclear on this point, but it seems that in the end, one has to pick either rebase or merge+rerere with all its consequences (good and bad).

Sources:

- [How to maintain long running git branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7752304/how-to-maintain-long-running-git-branches)
- https://gist.github.com/canton7/1570681